# Count no of <li> in left side and right side of a particular <li> in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to know how many `<li>` in the left side and how many `<li>` at the right side of a specific `<li>` in a `<ul>`.

For ex here I want the output that for the specific `<li class="active-slide">` `2` `<li>` at the left side and `1` at the right side.

Is it possible through `jquery`

```
<ul id="slider_donor" class="clearfix">
 <li id="slider_1">
 <li id="slider_2">
 <li id="active-slide" class="active-slide"> 
 <li id="slider_3">
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nextAll() and prevAll() to find out the next all previous siblings then get the length of those objects

```
var $active = $('.active-slide');
var rights = $active.nextAll().length;
var lefts = $active.prevAll().length;
```

Comment: although it is not needed here, but as far as it can be a new concept for OP, I think you batter consider the selector parameter in these 2 jQuery functions: `$active.prevAll("li").length`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
var leftLIs = $('.active-slide').prevAll('li');
```

to get all the `li` which are the previous siblings of your `.active-slide`.

As well as [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/);

```
var rightLIs = $('.active-slide').nextAll('li');
```

to get all the `li` which are the next siblings of your `.active-slide`.